# LESS mixin - Output values without quotes

Tags: css, less

I am trying to write a LESS mixin with multiple input parameter values for CSS transforms. The input values are the type of transformation to be done and the value associated with the transformation.

For example, consider the code given below:

```
.transform(@type; @value){
}
```

If I give input as `type='rotateY'` and `value='360deg'`, the output should be `transform: rotateY(360deg)`. I have tried the below options but none of them seem to be working (output is mentioned as comment).

```
transform: "@{type}(@{value})"; /* Output: "rotateY(360deg)" */
transform: @{type}(@{value}); /* Output: Compiler error */
transform: @type(@value); /* Output: rotateY 360deg */
```

How should I code it to get the output as required? Please help.

Note: The mixin code has a lot of other items also, I have posted just the line that needs fixing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just escape the string using `~` like shown below. Doing this would make sure that the quotes are not printed in the output CSS.

**Input Code:**

```
transform: ~"@{type}(@{value})";
```

or

```
transform: e("@{type}(@{value})");
```

**Mixin Call:**

```
.transform(rotateY;360deg);
```

**Output CSS:**

```
transform: rotateY(360deg);
```