# less mixin name is evaluated to colour/color

Tags: css, less

I have a less file to define a bunch of colours/color. Each class name contains the name of the relevant colour, such as `.colourOrange{..}`  or `.colourBorderOrange{..}` or `navLeftButtOrange{..}`.

To make this simple I have a mixin that uses a parameter name: colour, and uses this to name the classes thus:

```
.completeColour(@colourName, @col) {
.colour@{colourName}{
    …
}
.colourBorder@{colourName}{
   …
}
.leftNavButt@{colourName}{
```

…..
    }
}

The problem is this **the names of the classes are being evaluated to the relevant colour**.  So instead of getting `.leftNavButtOrange{}` I get `.leftNavButt#ffa500{}` in the resulting CSS

Is there a way to stop this with a compiler argument or something. Basically I don't want the parameter to be evaluated, read but not evaluated.  Can I do this with a compiler argument or do I need to change the names so they don't match a color such as myAppOrange or something.

Comment: Did you try putting the value within quotes?

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought would workf, but it won't compile: I tried this .completeColour("Orange",@orange); and this .completeColour('Orange',@orange); in the code that calls the mixin.  And in the mixin itself I tried this: .colourBorder'@{colourName}'{ and this .colourBorder"@{colourName}"{  All o

Comment: This `.completeColour(~"white",1)` should work mate. I just tried. Doing it this way would explicitly tell the compiler that the value is a string and not a color.

Comment: @Harry yeah fantastic works a treat.  So where does that tilda come from I don't see this in the docs? Nice one.  Do you want to write this as an answer and I'll mark it right

Comment: The `~` is used to [output a string without the quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614621/less-mixin-output-values-without-quotes/19614647#19614647) wherever it is being used. (In the Less docs you would find it as [`e("a")`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e)). This is a workaround mate. I am not sure if this is the best/only solution, so I would wait a while and see if there are any better solutions before adding an answer :)

Comment: I checked the Less GitHub page and found a couple of threads where this option is given as the work-around. So have added my comment as an answer citing those threads as sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a legacy feature of Less. For the time being, one of the below work-around solutions could be used to overcome this color name to hex code conversion.

```
.completeColour(~"Orange",1);
```

or

```
.completeColour(e("Orange"),1);
```

Both the options explicitly tell the compiler that the value being passed is a String and not a Color and hence Less compiler would not convert it to the corresponding hex code.

**Sources:**

1. [Less GitHub - how to avoid color name be translated into color value?](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2018)
2. [Less GitHub - Compilation of named colors results in hex values being used incorrectly in interpolations](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1595)

**Update:** Starting from version 2.0.0, this color name to hex code conversion would not happen if the color is mentioned explicitly as a name and has no other color based operations on it. Version 2.0.0 is currently in beta mode.

(**Official Update:** [V2 Upgrade Guide](http://lesscss.org/usage/#v2-upgrade-guide-language-changes) | **Original Source:** [More consistent named color variables](https://github.com/less/less.js/pull/1604)).