# Prevent variable color name to be converted into hex in less class names

Tags: css, less, lesscss-resources

I want to use a variable that will contain the name of a color (red, blue, green, etc) and to define some class style rules. For example:

```
.mixins-common-components(@colorName, @backgroundColor, @textColor){
  .btn{
     &.@{colorName}{
         color: @textColor;
         background-color: @backgroundColor;
         border-color: "";
     }
  }
}

.mixins-common-components(blue, #3781f7, #4b8df8);
```

This will return to me something like this:

```
.btn.#0000ff {
  color: #4b8df8;
  background-color: #3781f7;
  border-color: "";
}
```

Well, the way that .btn is displayed it's not ok. I would like to display it like this:

```
 .btn.blue{ ... }
```

I notice that less is automatically converting the color name into HEX value. I also tryied with quotes but it seems is not a good solution either.
Is there any solution to fix this into an elegant way?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a better way at the moment mate. However, as mentioned in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661662/less-mixin-name-is-evalutated-to-colour-color/25662327#25662327) answer there is a proposal to do away with this conversion in Less 2.0.0.