# how to define variable in less

Tags: css, less

I am trying to set up variables for media query breakpoints in less:

My definition looks like this:

```
@sm-screen: "(min-width: @{screen-sm-min}) and (max-width: @{screen-sm-max})";
```

So when I try to use it I do the following:

```
@media @sm-screen {
   .something {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

It nearly works but it ouputs the double quotes as well so the compiled css ends up looking like:

```
@media "(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" {
    .something {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

how do I define it so that the compiled CSS doesn't have double quotes wrapped round it? I tried just getting rid of them from the variable definition but then less won't compile I get the following error:

```
ParseError: Expected ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fund-manager\resources\assets\less\variables.less on line 11, column 14:
```

Comment: Please escape the variable value like mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614621/less-mixin-output-values-without-quotes/19614647#19614647) to avoid the quotes getting printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to escape the string with a ~ character like so:

```
@sm-screen: ~"(min-width: @{screen-sm-min}) and (max-width: @{screen-sm-max})";
```